# mongoose findById would not work with correct Id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was creating a database storing user information. Previously, the system worked well, after I performed npm update of mongoose, the system failed and I dont know why. The following is the error message I encountered.

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" at path "_id" for model "User"
```

Then, I write some simple testing code to test if the database is connected successfully. For example:

```
User.findOne({firstName: "David"}, function(err, user){console.log(user.lastName)});
```

The above worked perfectly.

I then found the corresponding Id from the database directly and create variable like:

```
var testId = "abcde"
```

and tried the following code:

```
User.findById(testId, function(err, user){console.log(user.firstName)});
```

Then it just output the error messages.

I have tried `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('abcde')` (abcde is just example) and it returned true. Therefore, I really have no ideas why it did not work...is it a mongoose bug?

Please help if you know the answer, thank you very much!

Comment: can you show your schema details

Comment: `var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  password: String,
  files: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'File'}]
});`

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem.

As I mentioned, the findById function did not work after I updated mongoose. I was struggling on the code for few days and when I woke up this morning, I suddenly thought of upgrading my node.js.

That worked.

After upgrading node.js from v4.x.x to latest version, everything worked fine : )

This taught me a lesson that I should not upgrade a single module alone and care of compatibility issue.